# Are songs written for anime openings or endings?

Tags: theme-song

I know that some songs in anime openings or endings come from popular J-Pop singers/albums (such as the Bleach opening Rolling Star by Yui). However, some opening songs seem to show up during the show, such as themes appearing during final battles. Are opening or ending themes generally written specifically for the show or are they taken from popular Japanese songs.

Comment: I think in the majority of cases, they are. Not only that, [they use the Anime as advertising](http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/2597/when-and-why-did-the-trend-of-130-long-openings-and-endings-begin) to sell the singles later on.

Comment: @GaoWeiwei If anything, it's the other way around, considering that my question was asked in March and the one you link to was asked in May.

Comment: @kuwaly That one is more general, as it also includes insert songs and background music. I'll let the others decide.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**In most cases, yes.**

A popular example of this is the anime [K-On!](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-On!). All the openings, endings and insert songs are written for the anime itself. They use the anime to advertise it and to sell more. Here is the [list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_K-On!_albums) of the anime's albums which if you observe, are really dedicated for the anime itself. It even had two live concerts, [Let's Go!](http://k-on.wikia.com/wiki/K-ON!_Live_Concert%3a_Let%27s_Go!) and [Come With Me](http://k-on.wikia.com/wiki/K-ON!!_Live_Concert%3a_Come_With_Me!!) where the seiyuu of each character actually played their character's instrument. Well K-On! has a plot that revolves around band members so it would be just appropriate to focus more on creating songs specifically for the anime's plot.

To prove that most anime theme songs (opening, ending, insert songs) are written for the anime itself is the existence of [Image Song](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ImageSong) or[Character Song](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_song).

> An image song or character song is a song on a tie-in single or album (often called an image album or character album) for an anime, game, dorama, manga, or commercial product that is usually sung by the voice actor or actor of a character, *in character*. It is meant to give a sense of the personality of the character.

So it would be more appropriate to write character song depending on the anime character's personalities and his/her situation on the anime he/she belongs to.

This [article](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/AnimeThemeSong) explains further about it and it also sites more detailed examples.