# Why are almost all anime episodes 20 minutes long?

Tags: anime-production

Why are all animes around 20 minutes long? Sometimes less or more due to the opening and ending, and some recap from last episodes...etc, but it's always around 20 minutes.

Why is that?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Presumably it's to fit into the standard 30 minute time slot allocated for the show.

- 20 min. episode
- [3 min. OP + ED (90 seconds each)](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/2597/when-and-why-did-the-trend-of-130-long-openings-and-endings-begin)
- Commercials

And it's about 30 minutes.

Comment: probably design like that because it meant for commercial TV Release first since if you look at RWBY, you could call it anime (styled like it but was not made in japan) and most episodes are less than 10 minutes but it was a Web Series